# How to configure OrientDB ETL to import an LinkList as edge attribute

Tags: json, csv, import, etl, orientdb

How can i configure a JSON file for initialice a mandatory attribute of type 'LINKLIST' when i import a .csv file?

My code is:

```
 { "edge": {
    "class": "Edgename",
    "joinFieldName": "FieldName",
    "lookup": "Vertex.FieldName",
    "direction": "out",
    "edgeFields": {
        "name": "myname",
        "Link_List": "[]"
        }
    }
},
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it as this:

```
{ "edge": {
"class": "Edgename",
"joinFieldName": "FieldName",
"lookup": "Vertex.FieldName",
"direction": "out",
"edgeFields": {
    "name": "myname",
    "Link_List": ""
    }
  }
},
```

Only double quotes are necessary.